# HTML5, jquery mobile app deployed as stand alone app

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have read a few forums and articles on this but can't get a clear answer.

I need to build a mobile app that can run on any platform/device. It looks like HTML5 + jquery is the best option but I need the application to do the following:

1. The app must run on any platform (Windows Phone, iOS, Android, etc).
2. It must work as a stand alone application. Meaning it must work without internet connection.
3. Because it is stand alone, I need a local database on the device. The database can be embedded in the app. I'm thinking SQL CE.
4. The local database on the device must be able to sync to a SQL Server database.
5. The app needs to interact with features of the device like the camera, or GPS device.

Is it possible to build such a mobile application?

I am using ASP.net MVC 4 to do the development.

Comment: Why did someone down vote the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use HTML5 and JQuery then the PhoneGap/Cordova framework would suit you best.

Phonegap is a cross platform framework that gives you access to the device features like GPS and Camera using a standard javascript API.

1. The app must run on any platform (Windows Phone, iOS, Android, etc).

   - Phonegap is compatible with all these and many more including blackberry. See here for       full list: http://phonegap.com/about/feature/
2. It must work as a stand alone application. Meaning it must work without internet connection.

   - PhoneGap runs as a native application inside each devices webview. It does not need access to a data connection to run
3. Because it is stand alone, I need a local database on the device. The database can be embedded in the app. I'm thinking SQL CE.

   - PhoneGap cannot run its own SQL Database like a standard native application but it can use the web standards Web Storage and Web SQL. Though this approach does have limitations. Read more about this here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage
4. The local database on the device must be able to sync to a SQL Server database.

   - This would be upto you to design and implement but can definitely be done
5. The app needs to interact with features of the device like the camera, or GPS device.

   - Most device features supported with PhoneGap. See above link for full support list.

If the lack of a full SQL Database support is a problem for you there are frameworks like Titanium Appcelerator that build a fully native cross platform app for you that may be more suited to your situation. 
http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-platform/

But if you're using HTML and JQuery to go cross platform then PhoneGap is your best bet.

**Edit:** Also there are plugins for PhoneGap to run a standard SQLite DB but this requires extra work on each platform. Every platform you develop for would require a compatible plugin. 
http://brodyspark.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/cordovaphonegap-sqlite-plugins-offer.html

Answer (score 1):

Use **PhoneGap**: http://phonegap.com/

or **Apache Cordova**: http://cordova.apache.org/

or **Intel XDK**: http://xdk-software.intel.com/